# Checking the triangle axiom of monoidal categories for the category $\operatorname{Vec}(\mathscr{C})$

Tags: ct.category-theory, c-star-algebras, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a (for simplicity, strict) rigid $C^*$-tensor category. Consider the monoidal category $\operatorname{Vec}(\mathscr{C})$ as defined in section 2.4 of the article [Operator algebras in rigid C*-categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.04620.pdf) by Penneys and Jones.

Note that the unit in this tensor category is the functor $1:=\mathscr{C}(-,1_\mathscr{C})$ where $1_\mathscr{C}$ is the unit of the tensor category $\mathscr{C}$.

It is not mentioned explicitly in the article, but the unitors are constructed as follows:

If $V\in \operatorname{Vec}(\mathscr{C})$ and $c\in \mathscr{C}$, then
$$(1\otimes V)(c)= \bigoplus_{a,b}\mathscr{C}(a,1_\mathscr{C})\otimes \mathscr{C}(c,a\otimes b)\otimes V(b) \cong \bigoplus_{b}\mathscr{C}(c,b)\otimes V(b) \cong V(c)$$
and the composition is explicitly given by (remember: $V$ is a contravariant functor):
$$\mathscr{C}(a,1_\mathscr{C})\otimes \mathscr{C}(c,a\otimes b)\otimes V(b) \ni f\otimes g \otimes v \mapsto V((f\otimes \iota_b)g)v.$$
This defines isomorphisms $(1\otimes V)(c)\to V(c)$ which induce the natural isomorphism $l_V: 1\otimes V \implies V$. This should be the left unitor for $\operatorname{Vec}(\mathscr{C})$. Similarly, the right unitor is defined.

Now, I want to check that the triangle axiom in the tensor category $\operatorname{Vec}(\mathscr{C})$ is defined, i.e. I want to check that the
composition of the associator with $r_V\otimes \operatorname{id}_W: (V\otimes 1)\otimes W \implies V\otimes W$,
$$V\otimes (1\otimes W)\implies (V\otimes 1)\otimes W \implies V\otimes W$$
is the same thing as $\operatorname{id}_V\otimes l_W: V\otimes (1\otimes W)\implies V\otimes W.$ Of course, this is equivalent with checking this equality as morphisms on each object $c\in \mathscr{C}$. However, I struggle to write down the details. Recall that the associator is given by
[image]

and somehow we want to get rid off the summation and these coefficients $U_{\alpha, \beta}^{\gamma, \delta}\in \mathbb{C}$, but I don't see why this will be the case. Some things simplify using Schur's lemma, but not the entire summation seems to vanish.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This follows immediately from the more natural formula for the associator. You were already told in the other question that there is a more general approoach to get this monoidal category (including a reference) (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435220), and I very much recommend this in order to avoid nasty computations.

Comment: The following paper, which considers the interplay between triangulated and monoidal structures, might be helpful: https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/AddJan01.pdf